# I am creating a small stock broking game as a side project and ran across a problem

Tags: vb.net

Currently, the game randomizes new stock price values for in-game days every time form5 closes and reopens. My aim is to have a randomized value at days: 2, 8, 5, 3, 13, 24, 29, at the moment the game creates a set value for day one, but when that in-game day ends and day two begins, both day one and two prices are randomized. When this form is closed and reopened the prices randomize for these 2 days again.

Here is the subroutine for form2: this form displays the available stock brands the user can 'invest' in, this shows the subroutine for when the user clicks on the tesla stock:

```
Public Shared Sub tesla(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Teslal.Click


    stockbrand.tesla()
    Teslastock.Show()
End Sub
```

Here is the subroutine for stockbrand.tesla:

```
Shared Sub tesla()
    stockrand(2, 8, 5, 3, 13, 24, 29)
End Sub
```

and then stockrand is responsible for generating the random values at the specified days:

```
 Public Shared Function stockrand(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer, ByVal c As Integer, ByVal d As Integer, ByVal e As Integer, ByVal f As Integer, ByVal g As Integer)
    For i As Integer = 1 To Form2.DAYno.Text

        If i = a Then
            Teslastock.at1986(a.ToString & "/8/86 1986", CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1)) * 2000)

        ElseIf i = b Then
            Teslastock.at1986(i.ToString & "/8/86 1986", CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1)) * 2000)

        ElseIf i = c Then
            Teslastock.at1986(i.ToString & "/8/86 1986", CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1)) * 2000)

        ElseIf i = d Then
            Teslastock.at1986(i.ToString & "/8/86 1986", CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1)) * 2000)

        ElseIf i = e Then
            Teslastock.at1986(i.ToString & "/8/86 1986", CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1)) * 2000)

        ElseIf i = f Then
            Teslastock.at1986(i.ToString & "/8/86 1986", CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1)) * 2000)

        ElseIf i = g Then
            Teslastock.at1986(i.ToString & "/8/86 1986", CInt(Int((11 * Rnd()) + 1)) * 2000)
        Else
            Teslastock.at1986(i.ToString & "/8/86 1986", Math.Sin(i) * 2000)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

the graph created by the function looks similar to a sin graph with exceptions at specified days and negative price values are multiplied by -1 to give a rational price

Teslastock.show shows the form on which the graph is placed

Comment: Not sure if there is a question here.

Comment: At least don't use `Rnd()`, use [System.Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0)

Comment: What are the types of the parameters that `Teslastock.at1986` expects? I ask because you appear to be passing Integer and then later Double.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your problems are caused by not having Option Strict On. It should be on. Project Properties -> Compile tab. Also for future projects Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults

Functions in vb.net need a `Type` and a `Return` statement. You are not returning anything so why are you using a `Function`? Use a `Sub`.

I don't know what `DAYno` on Form2 is but when I see a `Text` property it means a `String` to me. You can't have a `String` in the `To` clause of a `For` loop, thus the `CInt()`

Declare an instance of the `Random` class at the `Class` level.
We only need a new random number (not a new instance of the `Random` class) once per iteration. Near as I could make out, it would be a number between 1 an 12. I barely remember `Rnd()`. The `Next` method of the `Random` class provides an `Integer` inclusive of the first argument and less than the second.

All those `If...ElseIf`s have nearly identical code. I tried to sort it out with a `Select Case`. The first 2 cases send an `Integer` to `at1986` but the third sends a `Double`, thus the 2 methods in the the `Teslastock` class with different signatures.

Maybe your problems will disappear with these corrections.

```
Private Rand As New Random()

Public Sub stockrand(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer, ByVal c As Integer, ByVal d As Integer, ByVal e As Integer, ByVal f As Integer, ByVal g As Integer)
    For i As Integer = 1 To CInt(Form2.DAYno.Text)
        Dim r = Rand.Next(1, 13)
        Select Case i
            Case a
                Teslastock.at1986($"{a}/8/86 1986", r * 2000)
            Case b, c, d, e, f, g
                Teslastock.at1986($"{i}/8/86 1986", r * 2000)
            Case Else
                Teslastock.at1986($"{i}/8/86 1986", Math.Sin(i) * 2000)
        End Select
    Next
End Sub

Public Class Teslastock
    Public Shared Sub at1986(strDate As String, aNumber As Integer)
        'Some code
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub at1986(strDate As String, aNumber As Double)
        'Some code
    End Sub
End Class
```